# how to share virtual sharepoint server and get it in host windows and visual studio?

Tags: sharepoint, virtual-machine, virtualization

I Installed windows 8.1 and then Installed visual studio 2013 on this win 8.1
because I need sharepoint server so I installed windows server 2012 r2 on windows 8.1 hyper-v and then Installed sql server 2012 and sharepoint server 2013 and create my first farm server 
now I want to create my sharepoint app in visual studio that is installed on windows 8.1 but when I tap to vs 2013 sharepoint solution give me the same error that as if sharepoint is not running on the local machine .
when I browse sp server admin center In windows 8.1 browser it's able to load sp server central admin 
also I installed sharepoint designer on windows 8.1 and it's able to create site with this virtual sp server but just visual studio is not able to find this virtual server ?
please help me how can I add this virtual sp server to my visual studio ( the visual studio that is installed on my win 8.1 ) ??
thanks
(forgive me for my bad english)
Best regards:
Raha

Answer (score 0):

Install VS 2013 on the hyper-v that your SharePoint server is installed on.  run VS 2013 from inside the hyper-v and you should now be local with your SharePoint server.

Good luck